# Need syntax to work with both Ansible shell & command module

Tags: shell, ansible, command

The below syntax works fine.

```
---
- hosts: all

  tasks:
    - name: run this command and ignore the result
      shell: echo "The server is UP since " `uptime`
```

However when i change shell module to command module I was expecting this to still work.

```
      command: echo "The server is UP since " `uptime`
```

But it does not print the uptime value with the command module.

Can I not have the same syntax to work with both the shell as well as the command module ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I not have the same syntax to work with both the shell as well as the command module ?

Yes, of course, by just manually doing the job that `shell:` is going to do and wrapping the string in `sh -c`

```
- set_fact:
    the_command: sh -c 'echo "The server is UP since `uptime`"'
- command: '{{ the_command }}'
- shell: '{{ the_command }}'
```

Comment: Correct, without the `sh -c` then `command:` will treat those as literal characters, since they are only meaningful to the shell. There is an `echo` binary and an `echo` built-in shell command, which is why you can feed `echo "alpha beta"` to both `command:` and `shell:` but you will get a very different outcome if you try `echo "hello, $USER"` since the shell parses string literals, but the `echo` binary does not